# Problem occuring when not using double typecaster

Tags: c, math

```
int sum, a;
sum=17;a=5;
double mean = sum/a;
printf("%f",mean);
```

In the above code, the answer I get is 3.0000000.
However when I modify it to (double)sum/a, the answer I get is 3.4000000.

Can anyone explain what is going on.

Comment: The format specifier for `double`s is `%lf`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Since both `sum` and `a` are integers, the result of their division will also be an integer.

Comment: Also, thats not the cause of the issue. `sum` and `a` are both ints, so the result is also int. Cast one to double first/

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 For `printf` both `%f` and `%lf` are equivalent (since all `float` values will be promoted to `double` values).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah ok. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: So if we want to get a proper answer when we divide 2 integers, we have to typecast them during the division itself to get the correct answer?

Comment: @LuciferG correct. Otherwise, it does integer division, so the result will have to be an integer too.

Comment: Okay, thank you all for the help.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a good book for learning C for beginners.